# Using mod_rewrite to allow friendly URL with or without slash

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create a mod_rewrite rule that will create a friendly URL that can be used with or without a trailing slash.

eg. domain.com/index.php?id=421 to be accessible by a user entering domain.com/421 or domain.com/421/ .

I currently have the (rather simplistic looking) rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1
```

which works fine so long as there is a trailing slash but if the URL is entered without one is is re-written to domain.com/domain.com/index.php?id=421

I'm completely out of my depth here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use this: `/(.*)/?$`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't make any difference! (have edited my typo...thanks for pointing it out)

Comment: That is the only way to do it. ¿Why the leading slash? Try this: `(.*)/?$`

Comment: If remove the leading slash I get a 500 Internal Server Error for both URLs!

Comment: OK. Give it a last try with this: `^([^/]+)/?$`

Comment: No luck with that either. Thanks for your help but I'm going to give up on it for the night and try and look at it afresh in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed this. Firstly the reason I ended up going round in circles for soooo long was that my browser was caching the .htaccess file (didn't know they did that!) and so whatever I tried had little effect! Once I had worked that out resolving the problem was a breeze thanks to all I had read during my many hours of frustration. My solutions is :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If anyone needs an explanation of this code most of it is covered at http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/.